# How to get Associated Products Price in Dropdown of Configurable Prdouts

Tags: magento-2.0

I am working in Magento 2. I want to display Associated product's price in drop down on detail page.

Like producctname + price
For example in screenshot:- Green + 10;

[image]

Let me know please how can I do it.
Thanks

Comment: Does the title have a typographical error here? Is "Prdouts" a thing, or should this be "Products"?